# How can I control list of LEDs in kernel space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, led

I am trying to build a kernel module for Linux to try to control a list of LED devices that will turn them on/off in a sequence.  For example, green --> red --> green --> orange, and then repeat.

I know it can be done simply in userspace, but this LED sequence needs to be happening when CPU is used intensively where the sequence will be slowed down dramatically, so I need to control it through Hardware.  I've using delay_on/delay_off, with usleep(), but just cannot get the timing right between 3 LEDs.

I know how to trigger each LEDs and assign them pattern individually, but I cannot do it collectively.

Can anyone show me how to obtain a list of LED devices?

Comment: Why kernel mode? Why not user-mode? You don’t need to use kernel-mode to control external hardware and it makes your code more brittle because Linux, unlike Windows, does not have a stable kernel ABI.

Comment: Refer https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/leds/leds-class.html

Comment: There is or is going to be a pattern trigger for LEDs framework. It’s exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: First of all, thank you all for posting.  The reason I am asking this is that the requirement is each must blink separately, and no empty LED can be detected, so the timing must be exact.  If I use blink set, chances are either two or more will be turned on simultaneouly, or sometimes, they all will turn off at the same time.  Even if I separate them with usleep().  If using blink_set() for triggering, the timing can be off.

Comment: Read this: https://lwn.net/Articles/768159/

Comment: Yes, but the LED pattern triggers still applies to one LED only.  Even if I set the pattern, it still set the pattern based on its current stage, not the state of the other LED.

Comment: If you need to have robust solution you probably may modify that trigger to operate over group of LEDs.

Comment: Yes, is there any way to access the parent of a class device?  Right now, the trigger only applies to each individual LEDs, so I am wondering is there any way to access the other LED through parents.

Answer (score 0):

To list the available LEDs in kernel code:

```
extern struct rw_semaphore leds_list_lock;
extern struct list_head leds_list;
...
struct led_classdev *led_cdev;
...
down_write(&leds_list_lock);
list_for_each_entry(led_cdev, &leds_list, node) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "LED %s\n", led_cdev->name);
}
up_write(&leds_list_lock);
```

In kernel code, you can use the following function to retrieve a 'struct led_classdev' matching a given LED name:

```
struct led_classdev *led_get_by_name(const char *name)
{
    struct led_classdev *led_cdev0 = NULL;
    struct led_classdev *led_cdev;

    if (name == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    down_write(&leds_list_lock);
    list_for_each_entry(led_cdev, &leds_list, node) {
        if ((led_cdev->name != NULL) && (strcmp(led_cdev->name, name) == 0)) {
            led_cdev0 = led_cdev;
            break;
        }
    }
    up_write(&leds_list_lock);

    return led_cdev0;
}
```

Once the 'struct led_classdev' retrieved, all kernel LED APIs can be used.

Pay attention that the LED name may be null in the registered 'struct led_classdev' while the LED name appears under /sys/class/leds. E.g., this the case for the ACT and PWR LEDs on my Raspberry PI 4 under Debian 12.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did eventually.  But my code was poorly written so I didn't post the solution.